# How to use: CreateIpForwardEntry under standard user account?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, acl

Is is possible to add policy, configure the system or to do something so that the program which runs under standard user account could manipulate in routing table using CreateIpForwardEntry method?

I wouldn't like to elevate the application in UAC, rather do something to allow the software to make some changes ....

Thank You

Comment: You can't do this, as the function requires admin privileges. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly states this in the description of the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` return value, and in the seventh through ninth paragraphs of the Remarks section. You can require your app to prompt for admin credentials using a manifest, but you can't use the API call without those credentials.

Comment: What then is the best way to run certain code (add an entry to a routing table) from app run in standard user account? It should be done transparently for the end user (without login/password prompting, UAC prompting etc). If I know login/pass for user account begin in admin group, Can I for instance create startup app which run the main one in elevated mode?